# How to shuffle jpg image files and rename sequentially with batch / Windows

Tags: windows, image, batch-file, sequence, jpeg

I have a 520 jpg files image sequence named:

```
001.jpg
002.jpg
.
.
.
520.jpg
```

I would like to shuffle the images (keeping the same sequence filenames) with a windows batch script.
Is this possible?

Comment: 'shuffle' by its very nature implies a change of sequence. Please use the [Edit] facility to make a better attempt at an understandable and on topic programming code question.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561997/batch-file-playlist-random-sort) should give you an idea of how to start.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to shuffle :

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Randomly renames every file in a directory.

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM 0 = Rename the file randomly.
REM 1 = Prepend the existing file name with randomly generated string.
SET PrependOnly=0

REM 1 = Undo changes according to the translation file.
REM This will only work if the file "__Translation.txt" is in the same folder.
REM If you delete the translaction file, you will not be able to undo the changes!
SET Undo=0


REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Do not modify anything below this line unless you know what you are doing.
REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET TranslationFile=__Translation.txt

IF NOT {%Undo%}=={1} (
    REM Rename files
    ECHO You are about to randomly rename every file in the following folder:
    ECHO %~dp0
    ECHO.
    ECHO A file named %TranslationFile% will be created which allows you to undo this.
    ECHO Warning: If %TranslationFile% is lost/deleted, this action cannot be undone.
    ECHO Type "OK" to continue.
    SET /P Confirm=
    IF /I NOT {!Confirm!}=={OK} (
        ECHO.
        ECHO Aborting.
        GOTO :EOF
    )

    ECHO Original Name/Random Name > %TranslationFile%
    ECHO ------------------------- >> %TranslationFile%

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DIR /A:-D /B') DO (
        IF NOT %%A==%~nx0 (
            IF NOT %%A==%TranslationFile% (
                SET Use=%%~xA
                IF {%PrependOnly%}=={1} SET Use=_%%A

                SET NewName=!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!!Use!
                ECHO %%A/!NewName!>> %TranslationFile%

                RENAME "%%A" "!NewName!"
            )
        )
    )
) ELSE (
    ECHO Undo mode.
    IF NOT EXIST %TranslationFile% (
        ECHO Missing translation file: %TranslationFile%
        PAUSE
        GOTO :EOF
    )
    FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%A IN (%TranslationFile%) DO RENAME "%%B" "%%A"
    DEL /F /Q %TranslationFile%
)
```

and this to make the sequence :

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a a=0
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
    set "idx=00!a!"
    ren "%%~I" "!idx:~-3!%%~xI"
    set /a a += 1
)
```

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not how this site works. You should provide a code you have problems with and we help you to fix the problems...

However, I have some spare time now, so I wrote this for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load file names in both "in" and "out" arrays
set "i=0"
for %%f in (*.jpg) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "in[!i!]=%%~Nf"
   set "out[!i!]=%%~Nf"
)

rem Shuffle "in" array and rename the files in opposite "out" order
for /L %%i in (%i%,-1,1) do (
   set /A "pos=!random! %% %%i + 1"
   for %%p in (!pos!) do (
      ren "!in[%%p]!.jpg" "!out[%%i]!.new"
      set "in[%%p]=!in[%%i]!"
   )
)

ren *.new *.jpg
```

Comment: Did you saw my answer?